# Robotics Events

Tags: robotics

I'll be putting on a robotics competition in a month, and would love to see a list of different sorts of events I might be able to run.  What are the types of competitions you are aware of, at all levels of complexity, suitable for the novice LEGO roboticist to the corporate-backed team of pros?

Here are some ideas off the top of my head, from extremely simple to rather advanced:

- tug of war
- drag racing
- line following
- mini sumo
- maze solving
- soccer
- robo magellan (navigating waypoints in an outdoor course)
- land-mine identification

Please list one idea per answer (perhaps with minor variations), upvote, don't duplicate, provide a brief description of the event, and, if you know of rules or more details, provide a link!

Comment: Community Wiki...

Comment: @vicatcu I agree.

Comment: Agreed ... but I can't see the Community Wiki checkbox.  http://english.stackexchange.com/privileges/community-wiki

Comment: @vicatcu, @andrejako, @clintonBlackmore, you have to flag a moderator. People were using CW to try to sneak in bad questions often on SO, so now it takes a moderator. Just flag for moderator attention and request CW, and as long as the question is good, we will take care of it.

Comment: Here's quite a list of different events: http://robogames.net/events.php

Answer (score 5):

**Sumo**

Two robots face off in a black ring with a white border.  Each tries to push the other out.  Typically there are three rounds; the first robot to go out loses the round, and, if the robots are stuck together for too long, the round ends in a tie.

There are different weight-classes for robots of different sizes.

[Sample rules](http://www.robotroom.com/SumoRules.html)

[Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot-sumo)

[Sample videos](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=robot+sumo#q=robot+sumo&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&ei=A3QvTaOANo72tgPC9KjOBQ&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CC0QqwQwAA&fp=bf7e8c81604a9a8f)

Answer (score 3):

**Micromouse (Maze Solving)**

Robots are placed inside a maze and need to navigate through it as quickly as possible.

- [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micromouse)
- [Sample rules](http://micromouse.cs.rhul.ac.uk/mtech/rules_main.shtml)
- [Sample videos](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=micromouse#q=micromouse&hl=en&prmd=ivnslb&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&ei=03UvTca6CpGisQPctfy5BQ&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=2&ved=0CD0QqwQwAQ&fp=bf7e8c81604a9a8f)

Answer (score 2):

**Line Following**

Robots follow a line (typically black electrical tape on a white surface) around a course.  Robots try to be quick and accurate.  Easy courses have rounded edges; more advanced courses have sharp edges or gaps in the line.

[Sample rules](http://www.robotgames.net/robotgames/Event_rules/2002_line_follower.htm)

[Sample videos](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=line+following#q=line+following&hl=en&prmd=ivns&source=univ&tbs=vid:1&tbo=u&ei=ZXIvTbaXJo32tgPf_qzfBQ&sa=X&oi=video_result_group&ct=title&resnum=1&ved=0CCQQqwQwAA&fp=bf7e8c81604a9a8f)

Answer (score 2):

rope climbing -- perhaps tweak the [Elevator:2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator:2010) competition rules to make it a little easier.

Answer (score 2):

For more complex competitions, you may be able to draw from various student hardware competitions.  An obvious choice would be the [FIRST Lego League](http://www.usfirst.org/aboutus/content.aspx?id=880#fll_history) competitions.

They have complete rule sets available (including field drawings and competition formats) for 2006-2010, all of which were pretty interesting and challenging competitions, as I recall.  You may be able to use small portions of the actual competition based on time available.

Another source would be previous IEEE Student Hardware Competitions.  I've been doing IEEE SoutheastCon competitions for the past couple years, and there are a few that could be solved using only LEGOs.  Once again, field drawings and competition format is available.

Of particular interest would be the [2007: Basketball](http://www.southeastcon.com/2007/students/#StuHardComp) and [2008: Return to the Moon](http://ewh.ieee.org/reg/3/secon/08/competition.html)

Answer (score 1):

**Robo-Magellan**

GPS-equipped robots navigate outdoor waypoints autonomously.

- [Sample Rules](http://www.robogames.net/rules/magellan.shtml)
- [Sample Videos](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&tbs=vid%3A1&q=robo-magellan&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)

Answer (score 1):

**Drag Racing**

A robot needs to race straight down a track as quickly as possible.

- [Sample Rules](http://homepage.mac.com/mrlaurie/robo/rules.html#dragrace)

Answer (score 0):

**Obstacle Course**

Robots are built to go down a "hallway" over obstacles.  The one that goes the farthest wins, or, in the event of a tie, the one that traverses the distance faster wins.  When we did it, using wheeled/tracked Lego robots, obstacles included things like:

- pencils
- candles
- books
- bins
- ramps
- chocolate bars
- pop bottles

While I don't have any photos handy, I've run the event twice now at it was a big hit!

Answer (score 0):

**Tug Of War**

Two robots, each less than 1000g, are tied together with a string, and one must pull the other 30 cm within one minute to win.

- [Sample Rules](http://homepage.mac.com/mrlaurie/robo/rules.html#tugowar)
- [10 minute tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3TI93NDDpkQ)
- [Tutorial Page](http://homepage.mac.com/mrlaurie/robo/tugowartutorial.html)